# What version am I running?

Tags: wordpress, 4.7

The latest version of civicrm no longer prints the version in the footer. Is this correct? How do I find the version I am running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have CiviCRM 4.7 then from the top menu:

> Administer > Administration Console > System Status

Your version number will be in the CiviCRM Up-to-Date section.

[image: System Status page]

[side note: the demo version of Wordpress CiviCRM does have the version number in the footer -- not sure why you're not seeing it.]

Comment: It's in the status page. It's not in the footer. v4.7.1.

Comment: It's only in the footer on internal pages, so that may be the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check the version from the file: `civicrm-version.php`
in the downloaded folder of civicrm.

File path : `civicrm/civicrm-version.php`

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to your DB you can look in the civicrm_domain table for field= version

Answer (score 3):

Another way from the API (4.7 onward) is to use the System.check API:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('System', 'check', array(
  'name' => "checkVersion",
));
```

to get something like

```
Array
(
    [is_error] => 0
    [version] => 3
    [count] => 1
    [id] => 5
    [values] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => checkVersion
                    [message] => CiviCRM version 4.7.2 is up-to-date.
                    [title] => CiviCRM Up-to-Date
                    [severity] => info
                    [severity_id] => 1
                    [is_visible] => 1
                    [icon] => fa-cloud-upload
                    [id] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the API, you can also do System.get, which returns something like:

```
Array
(
    [is_error] => 0
    [version] => 3
    [count] => 1
    [id] => 0
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [version] => <3-part version number>
                    [uf] => <CMS type>
                )

        )

)
```